# Compare 2 Database all rows - different rows = output

Tags: sql, sql-server, compare

i need a little bit help.
I have a developer DB (dev_home), in this db are many tables.
I need a compare to another DB (real_home).

The Tables are the same, but the table_names not! 
For example i develop @ dev_home, in the table personal.
In this table i've created new field, which are not exist in @real_home DB.

Comment: You can use Visual studio schema compare to see the differences in SCHEMA only. For Data compare you can look for RED GATE tools if i am not wrong.

Comment: You said the structure of tables is the same but the table names are different. There is no automated tool that is going to search every table looking for a table that has the same structure. What would happen if you have two tables in a single database with the same structure but different names. You are going to have to map which table name in DatabaseA is the "same" table name in DatabaseB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tools that do this i.e. compare two different instances of a database or two different databases etc ..
Such as

**Red-Gate's SQL data comparison tool**

or

You can also use **Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition (Free)**